# Upfront payments and escrow

Tags: payment-terms

On fixed-price projects I've generally worked for 50% up-front, which I believe is more or less standard for software development-related freelancing. I'll sometimes ask for less than 50% if the budget is high.

**Is up-front payment still a standard when escrow is available, or does escrow entirely replace the up-front system?** Please note I am not asking whether up-front payment is standard in general or what percentage to charge, just whether it's *still* a standard when escrow is used for the payments.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's OK. I ask from 20% to 50% depending on the budget. If the project has large budget, you will have hard time convincing client to pay 50% upfront.

In large project, I also request milestone payments. We plan the project, set milestones from 2 weeks to 1 month, and when it's finished, they pay for it. This way, I don't wait for money a lot, and they pay smaller chunks.

Comment: How large is a "large budget"?

Comment: Any sum that is large in your opinion. For someone it's $500, someone $5000, and someone $50k. It also depends what a client thinks it's large. So you just have to rely on your hunch but also talk it thru with the client.

Comment: Is this answer specifically related to when escrow is involved?

Comment: Why not? Escrow is just a guarantee that the client has money to pay you for your work. So at the start of a milestones, a client can put the money into escrow and release it once you have completed the milestone.